# Reversing Linked List with Recursion, using STL

Tags: c++, templates

**Code for Reversing Linked List with Recursion, using STL**

```
          #include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class node
{
public:
    T data;
    node<T> *next;
    node(){ next = NULL; }
    node(const T& item, node<T> *nextnode = NULL)
    {
        data = item;
        next = nextnode;
    }
};
template<typename T>
class Reverse_list
{
private:
    node<T> *head;
    void reverse(node<T> *front);
public:
    Reverse_list(){ head = NULL; }
    //template<typename T>
    void Reverse();
    template<typename T>
    void Display( list<T>& alist );
};


int main()
{
    Reverse_list <int> rl;
    list<int> intlist;
    int size, no;
    cout << "Size of List ?? ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the " << i <<" "<< "element";
        cin >> no;
        intlist.push_front(no);
    }


    rl.Display(intlist);

    rl.Reverse();
    rl.Display(intlist);
    _getch();
    return 0;

}

template<typename T>
void Reverse_list<T>::Display(list<T>& alist)
{
    list<int>::iterator iter = alist.begin();
    while (iter != alist.end())
    {
        cout << *iter << "  ";
        iter++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Reverse_list<T>::reverse(node<T> *front)
{
    if (front->next == NULL)
    {
        head = front;
        return;
    }
    reverse(front->next);
    node<int> *back = front->next;
    back->next = front;
    front->next = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
void Reverse_list<T>::Reverse()
{
    reverse(head);
}
```

The above code generates 2 errors.

Error 1) No instance of function template matches the argument list. ( No error number.)

If I remove line 1 ( mentioned in a code ) then above error is no more. ( Why? )

Error 2) C2783: 'void Reverse_list::Reverse1(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

How to solve above errors.

In above program , I **wanted to pass " head" node** ( which is private ) as
**argument to Reverse function**. But we can not access private member outside of the class. So I passed indirectly. Is this a correct way of passing ?? Or there is some other way of accessing private data ??

Comment: Why do you need a Reverse function to be a template?

Comment: Anything wrong with `intlist.reverse()`?

Comment: @ teivaz : Actually I want to learn STL in C++. So I have started to learn with simple programming. But fear that, because of pure STL , my professor will think that, I do not know logic. So middle way is , write a program with STL and our logic. That's why I accepted linked list with STL but reversing with logic.

Comment: It looks like you need to practice template programming a bit before you launch into this. Start with some simple templates and the errors you've made will become clearer.

Comment: It's not clear what the `std::list` is doing there if you're implementing your own list. You also can't define functions within other functions. It looks like you should review some basic C++ without templates before you launch into this.

Comment: @ molbdnilo : I knew something is wrong ( I wrote like in the post also) But did not get it so tried abruptly.  Without STL and object oriented approach, just passing "head" node , to Reverse() function , list can be reversed but in above scenario how to do .... Can you help ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your intentions but...

You're trying to declare a method (`reverse()`) inside another method (`Reverse()`) ? Uhmmm....

We return to this later.

Imagine that the following instruction is correct instruction of `Reverse_list<T>::Reverse()`

```
node<T> *back = front->next;
```

Why you declare `back` as a pointer to a generic `Node<T>` when you assign `front->next` (so a specific `Node<int>`) to it?

If you define `back` as a `node<int>` pointer, the method `Reverse()` has no longer reason to be a template (dependant from `T`) method. And you can avoid both  errors.

With your actual code, when you call

```
rl.Reverse();
```

you call a template method but the compiler doesn't know how to determine the type `T`. You could explicit it in this way

```
rl.Reverse<int>();
```

but, as written before, I thik it's better if you remove the whole template part.

Or, alternatively, you can transform the whole class in a template class; where `head` is a pointer to a generic `Node<T>`, not a specifica `Node<int>`.

Something like (if I understand correctly your intentions)

```
template <typename T>
class Reverse_list
 {
   private:
      node<T> *head;

      void reverse (node<T> * front);

   public:
      Reverse_list() : head(NULL)
       { }

      void Reverse();
      void Display(list<T>& alist);
 };

template<typename T>
void Reverse_list<T>::reverse (node<T> * front)
 {
   if (front->next == NULL)
    {
      head = front;
      return;
    }
   reverse(front->next);
   node<T> *back = front->next;
   back->next = front;
   front->next = NULL;
 }

template<typename T>
void Reverse_list<T>::Reverse()
 { reverse(head); }
```

In this case, in `main()`, `rl` should be declared as

```
Reverse_list<int> rl;
```

fixing `T` as `int`, and the call to `Reverse()` should be

```
rl.Reverse();
```

**--- EDIT 2016.05.10 ---**

With the "template Reverse_list" solution, you should correct three points (at last).

1) in `Reverse_list` class declaration, you have commented the `template<typename T>` row before `void Reverse()`; good; you should delete (comment) the same line (for the same reason) before `void Display( list<T>& alist );`; so the class become

```
template<typename T>
class Reverse_list
{
private:
    node<T> *head;
    void reverse(node<T> *front);
public:
    Reverse_list(){ head = NULL; }
    //template<typename T>
    void Reverse();
    //template<typename T>
    void Display( list<T>& alist );
};
```

2) `Display()` now is a method of a templated class; so the line

```
list<int>::iterator iter = alist.begin();
```

become

```
list<T>::iterator iter = alist.begin();
```

3) `reverse()` now is a method of a templated class; so the line

```
node<int> *back = front->next;
```

become

```
node<T> *back = front->next;
```

Comment: You got my intention correctly. But have some doubt.                                                       1) In main() , why rl should be declared as Reverse_list<int> rl   ??                        2) Why you made  void reverse (node<T> * front)  as private ??

Comment: (1) you should declare `rl` as `Reverse_list<int>` **if** you transform `Reverse_list` in a template class for revers generic list; it's the only mode (the only mode I know) to tell to the compiler the specific class `T` (`int`, in your case; if you mantain `Reverse_list` as a not-templete class (able only to revers lists of integers) you should declare `rt` as a simple `Reverse_list`, like now;

Comment: (2) I've made `reverse()` as `private` because it's used only by another method of the class and I didn't see any reason to make it `public`; if you intend use it directly (like `Reverse()`) you can declare it `public`, but I suggest to declare a method `public` only if there is a reason to declare in `public`; declare it `private` (or `protected`) otherwise

Comment: (2 bis) now that i think best... `reverse()` could be `private` and `static`, because don't use anything of an actual `Reverse_list` object

Comment: (3) sorry for my bad English  :-(

Comment: I got all your points. Thank you for the help. But still I am facing one error.         Error :  C2244: 'Reverse_list<T>::Display' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Comment: Can you update the code in you answer? I suppose your actual code is different.

Comment: So you have choose to adopt the "template class" solution. Good. I think it's a more flexible solution. I see three problems to correct. Some minutes and I add the correction at the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! All errors are gone but unfortunately Showing Unhandled Exception at 0*013c5EB . Access violation reading location. error appearing while showing output. List is printed properly but ( I think ) problem in reversing.

Comment: Can you tell me concept behind when to write and when not to write template<typename T>  ( you have suggested changes regarding this in your latest edit. ) If you have any source / link , please share.